# Flex Mobile Gesture event : how to slide between 2 views like Google+ Mobile?

Tags: apache-flex, view, air, gesture

[Flex 4.6 - Air mobile application - Android target]

I would like to move (right or left according the current view) between 2 views when I move my finger on the mobile screen; for example with Google+ mobile application, in profil section, you can change the view just on move your finger on the screen, and the offset and the moving speed must be checked before change complete view.

Thank you very much !

Anthony

Comment: You may consider revisting some of your previous questions and selecting answers as appropriate.  If no answer is appropriate feel to provide your own answer if you now know more.  People on this site are more likely to help you if they think you are a contributing community member.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple application to do just that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" firstView="views.GestureViewChangeView1" applicationDPI="160"
                             initialize="view1_initializeHandler(event)"  >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            protected function view1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

This is the main application file, it just sets the input mode to Gesture.  It does specify the firstView, GestureViewChangeView1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="GestureViewChange1" gestureSwipe="swipeHandler(event)"
    >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            public function swipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                switch(event.offsetX)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // swiped right
                        break;
                    }
                    case -1:
                    {
                        // swiped left
                        this.navigator.pushView(GestureViewChangeView2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                switch(event.offsetY)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // swiped down
                        break;
                    }
                    case -1:
                    {
                        // swiped up
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }           


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="View 1" />

</s:View>
```

This view just displays a simple label and listens to the gestureSwipe event on the view tag.  In response to that it push a new view onto the Navigator, GestureViewChangeView2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="GestureViewChangeView2" gestureSwipe="swipeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            public function swipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                switch(event.offsetX)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // swiped right
                        this.navigator.popView();
                        break;
                    }
                    case -1:
                    {
                        // swiped left
                        this.navigator.pushView(GestureViewChangeView3);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                switch(event.offsetY)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // swiped down
                        break;
                    }
                    case -1:
                    {
                        // swiped up
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }           


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="View 2" />   

</s:View>
```

This view is almost identical to the previous one.  It changes the label.  On a swipe right it goes back, and on a swipe left it adds on GestureViewChangeView3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="GestureViewChangeView3" gestureSwipe="swipeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            public function swipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                switch(event.offsetX)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // swiped right
                        this.navigator.popView();
                        break;
                    }
                    case -1:
                    {
                        // swiped left
                        break;
                    }
                }
                switch(event.offsetY)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // swiped down
                        break;
                    }
                    case -1:
                    {
                        // swiped up
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }           


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="View 3" />

</s:View>
```

This view listens to swipe right to go back.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
But it's not the behavior expected : in your case, you don't take account the moving speed, the distance done, and the transition view start and finish (not possibility to revert and to stay initial view). Just like Google+ mobile for example.

Comment: Assume I don't know how the Google+ app works.  What is your expected behavior?  I don't understand why this doesn't answer your question.  I don't know how you want to take into account the moving speed or distance in relation to the transition.  I used the default transition in my samples, but you can use any transition you wish.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after isn't possible out of the box with Flex. Other than on iOS/Android, the swipe gesture handler only gives you -1, respectively 1 values, as can be seen in Flextras' example, neither the position of your touchpoint on the screen, nor the speed of movement.
So the slide transition on swipe like on iOS (or Google+ mobile I presume) that looks like you're moving existing containers on the screen isn't possible with that, unfortunately.

I have yet to see someone implement a gesture like that for Air, but I wouldn't say it isn't at all possible. If someone has seen an implementation, shoot! ;)